# MySQL query to get a count of active events in each of a year

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Table with over 10 million records where it stores historical record of events. The table structure is:

```
id   start_date   end_date
1    2023-01-01   2023-04-05
2    2023-01-06   2023-02-01
3    2023-04-01   2024-01-05
```

I'm trying to find the number of events that were active for each month of the year. I also have a calendar table which is populated with every single day/month/year.

So for example for 2023-01 it should result in 2 events and for 2023-04 it should also return 2.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT
    calendar.calendar_month,
    calendar.calendar_year,
    COUNT(*) AS active_events_count
from calendars calendar
LEFT JOIN
    events AS e
ON
    calendar.calendar_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(e.start_date, '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(e.end_date, '%Y-%m-01')
GROUP BY
     calendar.calendar_year,   calendar.calendar_month
ORDER BY
    calendar.calendar_year,   calendar.calendar_month
```

The problem is I'm getting a lot of duplicated rows in the result.

EDIT: Here is an example of a duplicate:

```
Id  start_date   end_date
10  2023-01-01   2023-05-31
```

However in this query I see the following result:

```
SELECT
    calendar.calendar_month,
    calendar.calendar_year,
    e.start_date,
    e.end_date,
    e.id
from calendars calendar
LEFT JOIN
    events e
ON
    calendar.calendar_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(e.start_date, '%Y-%m-01') AND DATE_FORMAT(e.end_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY
where
e.start_date >= '2023-01-01'
and e.id = 10
ORDER BY
    calendar.calendar_year,   calendar.calendar_month, id
```

Result:

```
Id  calendar_year   calendar_month  start_date   end_date
10  2023            1               2023-01-13   2023-01-13
repeated 31 times
```

Comment: What result do you get?  What's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: @RobEyre It's giving me a lot of duplicated result for the same ID

Comment: You might want to change your date range matching so that the end date check is `DATE_FORMAT(e.end_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY` - basically you're looking for the last day of the month that `end_date` is in (at the moment it's using the first day of the month)

Comment: @RobEyre Thanks, that's a good point. I have updated that but I'm still getting duplicated records for same IDs. Some Ids are repeated 20+ times

Comment: Can you isolate a specific example?  Perhaps choose an id that's showing up where it shouldn't and show the details so we can debug

Comment: I think it might be because of the way you're matching using `calendar_date` but grouping against `calendar_year` and `calendar_month` (so you'll end up with multiples according to days in month etc).  Try changing `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT e.id)` and see if that helps.

Comment: @RobEyre I added an example in the question.

Comment: Yes, I think it's due to the way you have every day in the calendars table, so you're getting a match for every day, but then summing them up per month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is useful, you could achieve your desired result set without the use of the calendars table, by using a recursive CTE to generate your date windows - like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE months AS (
  SELECT
    CAST('2023-01-01' AS DATE) AS first_day,
    LAST_DAY(CAST('2023-01-01' AS DATE)) AS last_day
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    first_day + INTERVAL 1 MONTH as first_day,
    LAST_DAY(first_day + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS last_day
  FROM months
  WHERE first_day < (SELECT MAX(end_date) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH FROM events)
)
SELECT
  MONTH(months.first_day) AS calendar_month,
  YEAR(months.first_day) AS calendar_year,
  COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) AS active_events_count
FROM months
LEFT JOIN events e ON
  e.start_date <= months.last_day
  AND e.end_date >= months.first_day
GROUP BY
  months.first_day
```